# SOAP UI 5.0.0 - Basic Authentication popup window is coming as blank while importing new WSDL

Tags: soap

[image]I just installed new SOAP UI version 5.0.0. I am facing a weird issue.

Whenever I try to import a new WSDL using an URL (which requires authentication), the basic authentication popup window of SOAP is popping up completely blank and I am not able to do anything beyond that.

I checked my Java version and it is the latest, I am not able to understand what is causing this?
See the screenshot as below for clarity.

Comment: No screenshot attached due to your rep level. Try host the image on an external service and link to it.

Comment: Thanks Deepend ... I have updated the link to the screen shot.

Comment: Sorry that link is not working.

Comment: Thanks Deepend .... Now it is visible in the post, please check.

Comment: Confirmed, visible in the post

Comment: hi All the above issue is finally resolved. I was having 2 versions of SOAP UI 4.5.1 and 5.0.0, may be there was some conflict or proxy issue. So the solution was, i uninstalled both versions of SOAP UI and then made sure proxy credentials are correct. Then re-installed version 5.0.0 only, now it is working fine. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Congratulations. You can post your solution as an Answer and accept it. Others suers in future will know that there is a solution to the problem.